# I have an array of object constructors and each object has 3 parameters one of them is an array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

so I need to make a program that has an array of object student and each student has parameter of (`int ID, String name, Double[] grades`)
the information of each student is written in a text file.
the text file goes to something like this

```
1. 1023910 jhon 40 90 10 85
2. 1023910  jhon 40 90 10 85
3. 1291009   max  89 92 49 100
4. 1102293   Michael 20 100 82 72

.... and so on"
```

I need to read what's in the text file and assign the information in the text file to the array of students that contains parameters (`id, name, grades[]`)
so far I managed to make a counter that calculated the number of students. but my problem is with the grades array.

Please I need you guys to explain it to me like an idiot.

Comment: Are those numbered lines part of the file, or just an attempt to format the file for stackoverflow?

Comment: Also, pretty sure you want us to explain it like _we would to_ an idiot, since explaining it like an idiot would be unhelpful to everyone.

Comment: Are you sure you want `Double` and not `double`?

Comment: I tried to format the text file so it would appear appropriate for stackflow.

Comment: yes I need this explained to me like I am an idiot X)

Comment: my English is not the best so I apologize

Comment: its double not Double

Comment: the information inside the text ends with a new line. so each student has a line which contains id, name and grades.

Answer (score 1):

You should post the code you have so far, but really the solution here is a nested loop.

In the loop you have so far you are reading out the student id and name.

You then want to split the remainder of the string by space (`line.split(" ")`) and then convert those values to double (`Double.valueOf(str)`) and put them into your student object.

```
String restOfline = ...;

String[] split = restOfLine.split(" ");
double[] grades = new double[split.length];

for (int i=0;i<split.length;i++) {
    grades[i] = Double.valueOf(split[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `Student` class with all your `int ID, String name, Double[] grades` as instance variables with appropriate getters and setters. Then make `array` or `List` of these Student Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Fast try...

```
public class Test {

  static class Student {
    String id;
    String name;
    List<Integer> grades;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "ID='" + id + "', name='" + name + "', grades=" + grades + "\n";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String file = "src/main/resources/data.dat";

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] items = line.split(" ");
      Student student = new Student();
      student.id=items[0];
      student.name=items[1];
      if (2 < items.length) {
        List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=2; i<items.length;i++) {
          grades.add(Integer.valueOf(items[i]));
        }
        student.grades = grades;
      }
      students.add(student);
    }
    br.close();

    System.out.println(students);
  }
}
```

output:

```
[ID='1023910', name='jhon', grades=[40, 90, 10, 85]
, ID='1023910', name='jhon', grades=[40, 90, 10, 85]
, ID='1291009', name='max', grades=[89, 92, 49, 100]
, ID='1102293', name='Michael', grades=[20, 100, 82, 72]
]
```